# Flutter dialogflow not accepting space in query

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es

Flutter dialogflow not accepting space in query. The query given to dialogflow client not accepting space. For example "Hi" is allowed but "Hi " is not allowed because it has space. Similarly it is accepting only one word and not sentence(since it has words with spaces). Need help.

```
import 'package:flutter_dialogflow/flutter_dialogflow.dart'; 
 void Response(query) async {
    _textController.clear();
    print("BLB calling $query= ${query.toString().trim()}");
    Dialogflow dialogflow =Dialogflow(token: "**api_key**");
    AIResponse response = await dialogflow.sendQuery(query).catchError((error){print("BLB $error ");});
    print("BLB called ${response.getStatus.getCode}");
    ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
      text: response.getMessageResponse(),
      name: "Eva the Bot",
      type: false,
    );
    //Tts.speak(response.getMessageResponse());
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
  }
```

Error message: `FormatException: Context name should contain only Latin letters (a-z A-Z), digits (0-9), underscore (_), and hyphen (-). Code: 400`
Dialog flow working perfect in console (right side 'Try it now').:(

Comment: try this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/encodeQueryComponent.html

Comment: @AmitPrajapati. Still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use API V2, it doesn't have this problem.
Use [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-chatbot-in-20-minutes-using-flutter-and-dialogflow-8e9af1014463) for set up.

You have to do it anyway, since [API V1 will be shut down on October 23, 2019](http://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent)

Comment: No. It is nothing to do with name of the bot. Since I am not sending bot name to dialogflow. I am getting error at catchError method.

Comment: That's my next plan. If I don't get solution then I move to API V2 :)

Comment: Moved to API V2.

Comment: Cool. Pls upvote the answer if it's helped you. The stackoverflow rating system doesn't count approved answer in specific tag rating, only votes.